# Launching ruby script with gem dependencies but with no framework at all?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm doing the following Nokogiri tutorial: http://hunterpowers.com/data-scraping-and-more-with-ruby-nokogiri-sinatra-and-heroku/

So I'm trying to launch this script in the terminal:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.930.com/concerts/#/930/"

data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

# Here is where we use the new method to create an object that holds all the
# concert listings.  Think of it as an array that we can loop through.  It's
# not an array, but it does respond very similarly.
concerts = data.css('.concert_listing')

concerts.each do |concert|
  # name of the show
  puts concert.at_css('.event').text

  # date of the show
  puts concert.at_css('.date').text

  # time of the show
  puts concert.at_css('.doors').text

  # show price or sold out
  # Remember, when a show is sold out, there is no div with the selector .price
  # What we are doing here is setting price = to that selector.  We then test
  # to see whether it is nil or not which let's us know if the show is SOLD OUT.
  price = concert.at_css('.price')
  if !price.nil?
    puts price.text
  else
    puts "SOLD OUT"
  end

  # blank line to make results prettier
  puts ""

end
```

with `$ ruby interesting.rb`

But nothing happens:

> alex@alex-K43U:~/rails/nokogiri$ ruby interesting.rb
>
> alex@alex-K43U:~/rails/nokogiri$

I used to do everything with Rails so now starting with an empty folder seems a bit confusing to me.

How to I install the gems in this folder and how do I properly launch the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access the site, and pop up the browser console and inspect the page, you will see that they changed the css classes of the concerts, so it isn't `.concert_listing` anymore.
Analyse the website and see what you can fetch, and how you can fetch it with Nokogiri.

Answer (score 1):

Looks normal to me!  Are you certain this line:

```
concerts = data.css('.concert_listing')
```

results in `concerts` having anything enumerable in it?  Have you tried this right after it?

```
puts concerts
```

Comment: Yes, I think that's not the problem. Maybe is the require 'open-uri' part? Is that a ruby module included with all ruby installations?

Comment: Yup, if you print 'data' out, the web page is in there...  I'm guessing your CSS selector is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely incorrect.  That tutorial is simply out of date!